# MODX Ext JS Retrieve Value From PHP File

Tags: javascript, php, extjs, modx

How can a value from a function in a PHP file be retrieved with MODx's Ext JS?

There is an `Ext.Ajax.request()` method which seems to retrieve the grid contents of the current page's grid rather than the PHP file.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Im not an EXT pro. I just work here. But this new article has some loading examples. http://hkwebdeveloper.com/modext-tutorial-series-part-1.html

Also hitting these 2 guys on twitter will get any ExtJS problem solved.

@_goldsky

@rtripault

Answer (score 0):

I think https://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/case-studies-and-tutorials/developing-an-extra-in-modx-revolution/developing-an-extra-in-modx-revolution,-part-ii should help.

2 basic things:

- Create JS file and extend MODExt
- Create processor file and extend modProcessor